# Multiple insert rows PostgreSQL Java Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm new to Spring WebFlux and I am trying to insert multiple rows to DB.

I'm creating a REST API for inserting data to DB.

I have a service for saving Flux object.

```
public Flux<FileUpload> create(FileUpload fileUpload) {
       Flux<FileUpload> attachments = Flux.just(fileUpload)
               .map(upload -> {
                   new FileUpload(upload);
                   this.fileUploadRepository.save(upload);

                   return upload;
               });

       return attachments;
}
```

And I have a RestController for Post request.

```
@PostMapping()
    public Flux<FileUpload> saveFile(@RequestBody FileUpload fileUpload) {
        return this.fileUploadService.create(fileUpload);
    }
```

Then I am passing this Json via requestbody in Postman

```
[
    {
        "filename": "test.pdf",
        "task_id": 2,
        "e_tag": 1234567890
    },
    {
        "filename": "test2.pdf",
        "task_id": 2,
        "e_tag": 0987654321
    }
]
```

My question is how to iterate over flux then save the data to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring data, then the `ReactiveCrudRepository` exposes a method which accepts a `Flux` as an argument and saves all to the db.

```
<S extends T> Flux<S> saveAll(Publisher<S> entityStream);
```

Please let me know if you are not using spring data and I will update this answer.